# PKCS1 encryption in Flutter won't work without reflection

Tags: flutter, rsa, pointycastle

I'm writing some code to encrypt data from a flutter client and send it to our servers. We are using PKCS1 padded RSA but i get the error below when attempting to encrypt the data.

```
I/flutter (12394): Bad state: Reflectable has not been initialized.
I/flutter (12394): Please make sure that the first action taken by your program
I/flutter (12394): in `main` is to call `initializeReflectable()`.
```

The code responsible for this is as follows.

```
static String encrypt(String text, RSAPublicKey pubKey) {
    var cipher = PKCS1Encoding(RSAEngine());
    cipher.init(true, PublicKeyParameter<RSAPublicKey>(pubKey));
    Uint8List output1 = cipher.process(utf8.encode(text));
    return base64Encode(output1);
}
```

I've managed to get a non padded sample running fine but the PKCS1 padded encryption requires a random generator that is initialized through reflection and flutter is saying no.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's probably because you are using a package that uses mirrors. You can't use such a package with Flutter.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer They have flutter compat.  [pointycastle](https://github.com/PointyCastle/pointycastle#without-dartmirrors-or-packagereflectable-flutter)

Comment: What version are you using? `1.0.0-rc2` is the only one that might work.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yeah on `1.0.0-rc2` An un-padded RSA encrypt works fine.

Comment: And you import it like explained in the link you posted above? In this case I'd create an issue in the plugins GitHub repo.

Comment: Yes the import is used correctly. I've forked and done a quick patch for now [here](https://github.com/duncanhoggan/pointycastle/commit/95bf515709202904beda9b71ae9a3770d3653710), would I raise it on the flutter/plugins repo?

Comment: No, pointycastle is a 3rd-party plugin. Ideally you'd create a Pull Request in the pointycastle repo.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer done, thanks for the sanity check.

Answer (score 1):

The reflection based `Random` constructor has been replaced with `FortunaRandom` and seeded.

```
_random = new FortunaRandom();
_random.seed(KeyParameter(_seed()));
```

The PR has been approved and is in master now so no one should have this issue ever again!